# Tensorflow gradientTape explanation

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand an API from tensorflow tf.gradientTape

Below is the code I get from the official website:

```
x = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x
  z = y * y
dz_dx = g.gradient(z, x)  # 108.0 (4*x^3 at x = 3)
dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)  # 6.0
```

I wanted to know how did they get dz_dx as 108 and dy_dx as 6?

I also did another test like below:

```
x = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x * x
  z = y * y
dz_dx = g.gradient(z, x)  # 1458.0 
dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)  # 6.0
```

this time the dz_dx becomes 1458 and I do not know why at all. Could any expert show me how the calculation being done?

Answer (score 0):

From `y=x*x`, we can have `dy/dx=2*x`. From `z=y*y`, we have `dz/dy=2*y`. According to the chain rule, `dz/dx=(dz/dy)*(dy/dx)=(2*y)*(2*x)=(2*x*x)*(2*x)=108`. `dy/dx=2*x=6`. The same derivation for your second example. BTW, in your second example, `dy/dx` should be 27 instead of 6.